# How to make a PInvokeable DLL

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke

I am trying to make a program which will need to execute a lengthy algorithm over and over again, so C++seemed like the obvious choice to me. However, in order to make it look aesthetically pleasing, and to make its other functions easier to make, I built it in C# and made the algorithm in C++.

As far as I am aware, the best way for me to use the C++ function in my C# program is to PInvoke it. However, when I try to PInvoke the function from the DLL, I get an error saying

`"Unable to find an entry point named <name> in DLL"`

When I made my DLL, I used Visual C++ and created a Win32 Console application, selected DLL from the choices, and created the function in the test.cpp file. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You should write the algorithm in C#.  It will be easier and is likely to be faster if done well (depending on what you're doing)

Comment: It will definitely not be faster. I ahve run it in both C# and C++, and C++ was 50x faster (I have to run it 9999 times, so this is not very surprising).

Comment: 50x faster in C++ could be because the C# code was poor.

Comment: I can assure you the C# code was very efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [export the function in the native DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8.aspx).

Comment: what about the __declspec(dllexport) thing?

Comment: That should work.  Try wrapping it in an `extern("C")` block.  Open your DLL in Dependency Walker and make sure that the export name is correct.

Comment: Combination of `__declspec(dllexport)`, `extern "C"` (note the precise syntax) and `cdecl` calling convention will result in function being exported with the name you intend. On the other side, when you do your `DllImport` you'll have to make sure you set `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl`.

Comment: Should I put all this in a new header file?